# Basic Python Programming to convert month number to month name using dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and only know the most basic level.
I am supposed to allow input of a date in the form of dd/mm/yyyy and convert it to something like 26 Aug, 1986.
I am stuck as to how to convert my month(mm) from numbers to words.
Below is my current code, hope you can help me.
** please do not suggest using calendar function, we are supposed to use dict to solve this question.

Thank you (:

```
#allow the user to input the date
date=raw_input("Please enter the date in the format of dd/mm/year: ")

#split the strings
date=date.split('/')

#day
day=date[:2]

#create a dictionary for the months
monthDict={1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun', 7:'Jul', 8:'Aug', 9:'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11:'Nov', 12:'Dec'}
#month
month=date[3:5]
if month in monthDict:
    for key,value in monthDict:
        month=value

#year
year=date[4:]

#print the result in the required format
print day, month, "," , year
```

Comment: avoid using the same variable name for different purposes (`date` in your code) in a single code block; it leads to bugs.

Answer (score 12):

Use Python's datetime.datetime! Read using `my_date = strptime(the_string, "%d/%m/%Y")`. Print it using `my_date.strftime("%d %b, %Y")`.

Visit: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Example:

```
import datetime
input = '23/12/2011'
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input, "%d/%m/%Y")
print my_date.strftime("%d %b, %Y") # 23 Dec, 2011
```

Comment: Yes, this is the most pythonic answer. Batteries included!

Comment: yupps i came across this answer several times when i searched for hel for my homework... but this is too 'high level' for us, we're not there yet (; but still tks a lot for sharing ^^

Answer (score 4):

```
date = raw_input("Please enter the date in the format of dd/mm/year: ")
date = date.split('/')
day = date[0] # date is, for example, [1,2,1998]. A list, because you have use split()
monthDict = {1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun', 
            7:'Jul', 8:'Aug', 9:'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11:'Nov', 12:'Dec'}
month = date[1] # Notice how I have changed this as well
                # because the length of date is only 3
month = monthDict[int(month)]
year = date[2] # Also changed this, otherwise it would be an IndexError
print day, month, "," , year
```

When run:

```
Please enter the date in the format of dd/mm/year: 1/5/2004
1 May , 2004
```

Comment: thank you so much too ^^ you have really made it simple and easy to understand for me (:

Answer (score 2):

After you have done split, you don't need to use index like day=date[:2]. Simply use say = date[0]. Similarly no looping is required to match dictionary values. You can see the code below.

```
#allow the user to input the date
date=raw_input("Please enter the date in the format of dd/mm/year: ")

#split the strings
date=date.split('/')

#day
day=date[0]

#create a dictionary for the months
monthDict={1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun', 7:'Jul', 8:'Aug', 9:'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11:'Nov', 12:'Dec'}
#month
monthIndex= int(date[1])

month = monthDict[monthIndex]
#year
year=date[2]
print day, month, "," , year
```

Answer (score 1):

When you split your date string, you will only have three elements (0, 1, and 2):

```
>>> date=date.split('/')
>>> print date
['11', '12', '2012']
  ^     ^     ^
  0     1     2
```

Thus, date[:2] will equal this:

```
>>> day=date[:2] # that is, date up to (but not including) position 2
>>> print day
['11', '12']
```

And `date[4]` will not exist, and neither will `date[3:5]`.

In addition, you need to call your dictionary value like this:

```
>>> print monthDict[12]
Dec
```

So to print the day, month, year combination, you would want to do this:

```
>>> print date[0], monthDict[int(date[1])] + ", " + date[2]
11 Dec, 2012
```

You have to use `int(date[0])` as your key in `monthDict[int(date[0])]` because you used integers as your dictionary keys. But your input (from the user) is a string, not integers.